# Rmarkdown and escape characters

Tags: escaping, r-markdown, character, kable

How can I print the sequence \\$ in R, as it is? I am working in RStudio, bookdown, inside a kable table in an R chunk. I tried four backslashes before the $ or five backslashes before the $ but did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to print `\\$`, you can set `escape = TRUE`.

One `.Rmd` simple file as an example:

````
---
title: "Example with escape = TRUE"
author: bttomio
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r kable}
library(kableExtra)
df <- data.frame("Example" = c("\\\\$"))
kbl(df, escape = TRUE)
```
````

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you bttomio, this is a nice example but I need also the two backslashes before the dollar sign.

Comment: I see your point. Did you try ```escape = T```?

Comment: Excellent, that's what I was looking for!